# Postgres sql: constraint no duplicate in an array of elemets

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I want to add a colum "cities" with a constraint to avoid duplicates

Right Table:

```
Name | Cities
John |"NY", "BOST", "NJ"
Peter|"CHI", "LA"
```

How do I add a constraint telling I don't want :
`Sam | "LA", "LA"`

Example of code

```
ALTER TABLE address
        ADD CONSTRAINT "check_cities_are_not_duplicate"
        CHECK (
            Cities <> ...
        );
```

Comment: Why don't you normalize your data model? Then this is as simple as creating a unique index

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2cd975f07fa560a85c871ca255a1bb1d)

I'd create a function which can check this:

```
create function check_duplicates (my_array text[]) 
returns boolean
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
    result boolean;
begin
    SELECT cardinality(my_array) = cardinality(array_agg(DISTINCT u))
    INTO result
    FROM unnest(my_array) u;

    RETURN result;
end;
$$;
```

Basicly the function counts the elements of the array (`cardinality()`) and compares it with following:

- `unnest(array)` expands the array elements into one row per element
- `array_agg(DISTINCT ...)` reaggregates this, but ignores duplicates
- `cardinality(...)` of on this new array

So, if the number of elements of the original array and the newly created array differ, the array has duplicate elements.

This function can be used in a check constraint:

```
CHECK(check_duplicates(cities))
```

Comment: As a side note: an immutable SQL function is a bit more efficient: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a08f14fd98d905a21abeb24224cd4a67